# Amicable numbers and third wheels

Tags: number-theory

Let $\sigma(n)$ be the sum of divisors function. i.e.
$$ \sigma(n) = \sum_{d|n} d$$

For instance $$\sigma(10) = 1 + 2 + 5 + 10 = 18$$

The standard definition of amicable numbers is a pair of numbers $m,n$ whose proper divisors sum to each other (i.e. divisors of the number excluding the number itself). We can write this using the above notation as $$ \sigma(n) - n = m$$ and $$\sigma(m) - m = n$$

Is it possible to have a "third wheel" $k$ such that $$\sigma(k) - k = n $$ but $ k \neq m $?

Collecting what we have we get $$\sigma(k) - k = \sigma(m) - m   $$

Or alternatively
$$\sigma(m) - \sigma(k)  = m-k   $$

After trying to do some obivous things like take the sum mod $m$ e.t.c. I got nowhere

Comment: Different numbers can have the same (proper) divisor sum, and I don't see why one of them being part of an amicable pair should prevent that. Have you tried a computer search?

Comment: $220,284,562$ ...